# Add New Text Box To Wordpress Twenty Seventeen Header

Tags: php, css, wordpress

The Twenty Seventeen header displays two text boxes: the Site Title and the Tagline. I would like to add a new text box at the top right of the screen. How can I do it?

**EDIT**

The [image of two headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okiH3.png) shows the header layout provided by the theme and the header layout I am trying to make (below).

In header.php I have added a container after the following line:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

For example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column column-one">
    <h1>Farm BBQ</h1>
    <p>Best Moose Burgers</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column column-two">
    <img href="https://moose.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column column-three">
    <p>123 High Road,<br />Rockwell Park,<br />London <br />E1 1AA</p>
    <h4><strong>07888 555 555</strong></h4>
  </div>
</div> <!-- end of container -->
```

This appears in the header but fails to deal with the pre-existing code and it is inconsistent with the way that the theme has been put together.

NOTE: I can now make use of any solutions which require bootstrap (CDN).

Comment: Have you already tried something? If yes, what? If not, seach for documentation and give a try. If you post your (non working?) code, it's more likely that we will recieve help

Comment: @Francesco Montesano I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying that if you are going to make any changes to theme at all you need to create a child theme.

You will need to modify your header.php file within the theme and add in the html element or see if there is already a widget area for that.

The way I would suggest going about it is:

1. Create a child theme
2. Add in your html to make it two columns within your .site-header. You will have to experiment a bit to get what you want. It may look something like this:

   ```
   <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
   <div class="xs-col-6(if you use bootstrap)">
   <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/header', 'image' ); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="xs-col-6">
   <span>Text in Here OR widget area</span>
   </div>
   <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'top' ) ) : ?>
       <div class="navigation-top">
           <div class="wrap">
               <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation/navigation', 'top' ); ?>
           </div><!-- .wrap -->
       </div><!-- .navigation-top -->
   <?php endif; ?>
   </header><!-- #masthead -->
   ```
3. Then think about what you would like to display in the second column and how easy you want to be able to change it. If you want to change it often you should create a widget area that you can edit from the admin ui.

Hope this helps give you some direction!

Comment: I have an active child theme. What do you mean by "make it two columns within your .site-header"? Is that a modification to style.css?

Comment: How do I get bootstrap on wordpress (is there a plug-in)?

Comment: Question 1. No, it's a modification to headers.php. If you look at the file you will see that I added two divs to make two columns in the header.

Comment: Question 2. I'm sure there is a bootstrap plugin, but normally you would download it, upload the files, then register and enqueue it within your child theme functions.php.

Comment: How do I do it without bootstrap?

Comment: You would need to add classes and set the width in css. I would highly suggest using bootstrap if you've never done this before. It can be difficult to get columns to behave correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142209/discussion-between-astrophe-and-peterg).